# Is there a standard way to get the nth `nextafter` floating-point value in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

C++ has `std::nextafter()`, which returns the next representable value after a given floating-point value *f*. In my case, I'd like to allow for *n* bits of slop in the lower mantissa bits, so 3 bits of slop would require getting the 8th next value after some given value *f*. I could call `nextafter()` eight times, but is there a better way to handle this?

For most values, you could get by with casting the FP value to `uint_64`, adding the tolerance (`1<<3` for 3 bits of slop), and then casting back to `double`, thanks to the layout of IEEE 754. However, that relies on IEEE 754 floating point (a good assumption, but not rock solid either).

(For background, I want to use this to hoist ray-surface intersection points, which are occasionally located inside the surface due to FP imprecision. Those familiar with robust floating-point will understand why `epsilon` is a terrible solution.)

Comment: It doesn't sound like you need exactly the 8th next value. Would multiplying f (assuming it is positive) with 1.00...001 be good enough?

Comment: You can also use the value of [`std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_iec559) to check if IEEE 754 is used, and specialize the function accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A naive approach could be to multiply by 8 the distance between a value and the next representable float, instead of calling 8 times `std::nextafter`

```
double advance_float(double x, int d)
{
    double step = std::copysign((std::nextafter(x, x + d) - x) * d, d);
    return x + step;
}
```

[Here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QnruraLTsFyb9Lsh) there are some tests, but it's up to you to determine if this is suitable for your use case.

**Edit**

As noted by [Steve Hollash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/566185/steve-hollasch), `x` may be so big that `x + d == d`. [Daniel Jour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1116364/daniel-jour) suggested to take advantage of `frexp` (and `ldexp`), but in the following attempt, I'll use a different approach to determine the direction.

```
double advance_float(double x, int d)
{
    const double to = std::copysign(std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity(), d);
    const double next = std::nextafter(x, to);
    return x + std::copysign(d * (next - x), d);
}
```

Note that it assumes that `std::numeric_limits<double>::has_infinity == true`, otherwise `::lowest()` and `::max()` must be used.

Those are some results

```
         x    d             previous                     x                   next
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           1  1     0x1.fffffffffffffp-1                   0x1p+0     0x1.0000000000001p+0
           1  8     0x1.ffffffffffff8p-1                   0x1p+0     0x1.0000000000008p+0
     3.14159  8      0x1.921fb54442d1p+1     0x1.921fb54442d18p+1      0x1.921fb54442d2p+1
      100.01  8     0x1.900a3d70a3d69p+6     0x1.900a3d70a3d71p+6     0x1.900a3d70a3d79p+6
     -100.01  8    -0x1.900a3d70a3d79p+6    -0x1.900a3d70a3d71p+6    -0x1.900a3d70a3d69p+6
       1e+67  8   0x1.7bd29d1c87a11p+222   0x1.7bd29d1c87a19p+222   0x1.7bd29d1c87a21p+222
       1e-59  8    0x1.011c2eaabe7dp-196   0x1.011c2eaabe7d8p-196    0x1.011c2eaabe7ep-196
           0  8 -0x0.0000000000008p-1022                   0x0p+0  0x0.0000000000008p-1022
4.94066e-324  8 -0x0.0000000000007p-1022  0x0.0000000000001p-1022  0x0.0000000000009p-1022
```

Comment: Interesting approach. As written, the `x+d` isn't what you're looking for, however. If x is large, then (x+d) == x. But I like the idea: compute the value equal to the lowest order bit with a matching exponent, scaled by the "slop", and then added to the original value.

Comment: @SteveHollasch True, that's the problem with `nextafter`, how to pass the "direction".

Comment: Adding `frexp` before this and `ldexp` afterwards should work, no?

Comment: @DanielJour Do you mean [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ala9TuM8cbaGnE8s)? It seems to "work", but I'm surely missing a lot of corner cases.

Comment: Marvelous. Not just a solution, but a bunch of new tools I wasn't aware of. With `frexp` in particular, I can move worlds. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, there is no standard function for this. Boost has you covered though: See [`boost::math::float_advance`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/next_float/float_advance.html). If you're using this for comparing two floats, you probably want [`boost::math::float_distance`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/next_float/float_distance.html) instead.

Comment: The link is not to the newest version. (That probably doesn't matter much.)

Answer (score 0):

Using a little endian architecture, when i know my inputs i can do it :

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double sunday_crafts_nextafter(double d, long long int step) {
    long long int tmp;
    memcpy(&tmp, &d, sizeof(d));
    tmp += d > 0 ? step : -step;
    memcpy(&d, &tmp, sizeof(d));
    return d;
}

double real_nextafter(double d, int step) {
    double b = step > 0 ? 1./0 : (step = -step, -1./0);
    for (int i = 0; i < step; ++i)
        d = nextafter(d, b);
    return d;
}

int main() {
    int step = 1 << 26;
    if (real_nextafter(1234, step) == sunday_crafts_nextafter(1234, step))
        if (real_nextafter(1234, -step) == sunday_crafts_nextafter(1234, -step))
            if (real_nextafter(-1234, step) == sunday_crafts_nextafter(-1234, step))
                if (real_nextafter(-1234, -step) == sunday_crafts_nextafter(-1234, -step))
                    puts("it works");
}


// to me "it works", res is 1234.000015258789100
```