# Alternative for nextafter when backporting to visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017

I am backporting a project from VS 2017 to VS 2013.
Looks like the function `std::nextafter` is not available in VS 2013.

Can anyone please suggest a workaround or alternative?

Comment: `std::nextafter` is available since C++11. See [How to change c++ standard in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29921621/995714), [How to change c++ standard in VS 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29921621/995714). VS2013 doesn't fully support C++11 and I don't know if it supports `std::nextafter` properly or not. Why do you use such ancient software?

Comment: In older C++ standards use `boost::math` instead [Is there a standard way to get the nth `nextafter` floating-point value in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59328864/995714), [Alternative to C++11's std::nextafter and std::nexttoward for C++03?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16335992/995714)

Comment: Googling "VS 2013 nextafter" gives this: <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/h0dff77w(v=vs.120)> Does `_nextafter(x, y)` work for you?

Comment: Why backport to VS2013? Using VS2022 would seem like a better direction.

Comment: For commenters asking about the "why", it's not that uncommon to have some enterprise contracts where their update schedule for internal software is basically equal to the lifespan of the IT head honcho.

Answer (score 2):

As other mentioned it is not clear why you need to go back to such an ancient version.

In any case, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/h0dff77w(v=vs.120)) for VS2013 contains this function:

```
double _nextafter( 
    double x, 
    double y  
);
```

Which is described as:

> returns the closest representable neighbor of x in the direction toward y.

It seems to be the same as [std::nextafter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter) that you wish to replace (where `x` is `from` and `y` is `to`).